# Spring OAuth2- Passing token in Authorization: Bearer

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am passing oauth2 token in Request header as Authorization: Bearer . But if you use for example Chrome developer tools you can see the token and basically copy it and use it to call our services. How can I prevent/hide the token so it does not show in developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

Developer tool are not designed to hide any data (e.g. you can use them to send cookies as well). So if you don't trust your users then don't issue tokens that can be used from an arbitrary client.